# WCF MTOM attachment how to set content-type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, content-type, mtom

I need to set a specific content type(application/pdf) for the binary part in an MTOM configured binding.

Is there anything in the config or in code I can do to have the content type set? For the filepart it's always "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"

Config:

```
<binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding"
 closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
 messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Buffered"
 maxBufferSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
 <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

What's currently sent to the service. The multipart header for the file should be application/pdf instead of application/octetstream

```
POST https://somewebservice HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Authorization: Basic authhash
SOAPAction: ""
Host: webservicehost
Content-Length: 24517
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


--uuid:b8366a06-3ecc-4bc4-9809-8c87ad459981+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header>[The soapmessageitself]</s:Envelope>
--uuid:b8366a06-3ecc-4bc4-9809-8c87ad459981+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636787311873257476>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream // This must be application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
%    
1 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> ...
```

Comment: It occurs to me you didn't specify what *kind* of binding that is...that is, what tag is it wrapped in?

Comment: Also...it would be worth seeing your sending code. That's the mystery code that makes this c# question after all :-)

Comment: The sending code was someWCFSoapClient.UploadAttachment(requestModel,fileBytes). The filebytes were not in the requestmodel itself but added as a second method call in the client method (generated by consuming the wsdl in Vstudio)

Comment: @Clay, where is your answer? :) I'd mark it as the solution

Comment: Sorry - I assumed from your answer I was going the wrong way

Comment: It's an answer to the question, I hoped there was something more simple than creating a CustomTextMessageEncoder

Comment: Yes, understood...It's a fairly tedious integration. I'm glad you got to where you needed to get with your roll-your-own solution. It was kind of you to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having to guess that you're encoding a response to a request. If so, you just need to add the content type header to your outgoing message:

```
OperationContext
  .Current
  .OutgoingMessageHeaders
  .Add ("Content-Type", "application/pdf" );
```

Not 100% sure, but you may need to clear any existing outgoing Content-Type header, first. I don't think it matters that your message is MTOM-encoded. That is theoretically transparent.

Also...just asking...why allow a 64MB buffered message when a streamed message takes so much less memory to transfer...and is likely to be just as fast or faster? You're pretty much guaranteed better performance in a heavily loaded service.

**Update**:

If you're lucky enough to be using a web api-type of binding (WebHttpBinding)...you can stream out your content pretty easily, specifying the content type. It's not that different than what I'd put in my answer above, but as you'd replied, *those* headers go to the wrong place.

Instead, it should be:

```
WebOperationContext
  .Current
  .OutgoingResponse
  .ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

There's a fantastic article/example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web/) that fully develops the idea...in a way consistent with your objectives.

If you're bound to an older soap binding, then you probably need is to write a custom message encoder. The technique is straightforward enough (if tedious). The basic idea is that you can take control of writing the body of the message in ways that are appropriate to your needs.

The encoder itself is trivial. The boilerplate that goes around it will be the tedious part. A custom encoder derives from the abstract  [MessageEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder?view=netframework-4.7.2). The important things to do are to override the `ContentType`, `MediaType`, `MessageVersion` properties and the `ReadMessage` and `WriteMessage` methods. There are variations of the `ReadMessage` and `WriteMessage` methods for dealing with streamed and buffered messages.

The ugly part is the boilerplate that you have to write to deploy your encoder. You have make an encoder factory, and a custom binding element. Not 'orrible, but noisy. There's a couple of examples of the whole ball of wax (including the factory and binding element support) in the in the example code package [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459)...which can save you some time.

Comment: Thx for your rsponse! However, this will add a header in the general SOAP header. I need to change the content-type header of the multipart item that is transmitting the file. I've updated the question with some more details. (good point ivm streaming!)

Answer (score 2):

As time grew short I solved this issue by manually constructing the soap call. As there is a bounty on this question I'll mark the answser that does the same but using the WCF libraries as the correct answer. Code sample below starring "byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf; name=test.pdf");" what I needed to do with WCF

```
static HttpClient client;
static object mutex = new object();
static HttpClient Client
{
    get
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            lock (mutex)
            {
                if (client == null)
                {
                    client = new HttpClient();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username + ":" + Password)));
                }
            }
        }

        return client;
    }
}

public static TResponse Send<TResponse>(string endpoint, string payload, byte[] file)
{
    string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    MultipartContent multipart = new MultipartContent("related", boundary);

    multipart.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    multipart.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"");
    multipart.Add(new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));

    ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);
    byteContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf; name=test.pdf");
    byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-ID", "<test.pdf>");
    byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; name=\"test.pdf\"; filename=\"test.pdf\"");

    multipart.Add(byteContent);

    var result = Client.PostAsync(endpoint, multipart).Result;
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    TResponse resultTyped = XmlHelper.ToObject<TResponse>(resultString);
    return resultTyped;
}
```